# Linux bash, command replace

Tags: bash, shell, clipboard, find-and-replace

How can I erase the `-` from clipboard?

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xclip -o | replace - "" | xclip
```

Bat this doesn't work
So

`replace \- ""` take no effect

```
]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.17.4-302.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 4 19:12:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tr -d`:

```
$ xclip -o | tr -d "-" | xclip
```